# What Contact Form 7 action should I hook into for seed submitted data AFTER validation and spam filters?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm building an API Integration with a Wordpress Plugin that forwards from's data to CRM's API.

I've got it working on Contact Form 7 by adding an action after 'wpcf7_submit'.

```
// wpcf7_submit available since ContacForm7 4.1.2, testes with 4.4
add_action("wpcf7_submit", "crm_forward_cf7_to_crm", 10, 2); 

function crm_forward_cf7_to_crm($form,$result) {

  // TODO has spam been filtered already?
  // TODO has form been validated already?

  $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
  if ( $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $posted_data = crm_filter_cf7_data($posted_data);
    crm_post_form($posted_data);
  }
};
```

**My questions are:**

Has this submission been filtered out by spam validation (e.g.: akismet) at this point?

Has CF7 validated this form at this point?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about akimeset (but judging form possible statuses it did some kind of spam validation by this time), but at this point CF7 has validated it.
You can check if it's valid and is not spam, from `$result['status']`;
Possible values are:

- validation_failed
- acceptance_missing
- spam
- mail_sent
- mail_failed

If validation has failed, you will be able to retrieve failed fields as an array from `$result['invalid_fields']` response from `$result['message']`